# Postfix configuration with Dovecot, MySQL, and SpamAssasin

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, spamassassin, thunderbird

I am relatively familiar with Debian and have been trying to setup a mail server with this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin).

Now i have gone through all the comments provided on the website to try route out the problem but they do not seem to work. I have come accross some similar problems on serverfault but they too do not work. My greatest challenge is truely making heads or tails of the stack trace.

I see a lot of warnings and some errors and cant tell what the route cause is. The biggest challenge is that this is my first time dealing with anything mail related/smtp.

The first error I resolved was this

```
Fatal: Error reading configuration: Invalid settings: postmaster_address setting not given
```

by adding `"postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com"` to the file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf`.
Note
Based on numerous posts the file to which this line is added to varies.

Now here comes the long stack trace i can't make sense of

```
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem: disabling TLS support
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: warning: TLS library problem: 28713:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem','r'):
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: warning: TLS library problem: 28713:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: warning: TLS library problem: 28713:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:722:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem: disabling TLS support
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: warning: TLS library problem: 28714:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem','r'):
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: warning: TLS library problem: 28714:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: warning: TLS library problem: 28714:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:722:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: warning: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.x.hostname.com does not resolve to address xxx.xxx.xx.x: No address associated with hostname
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: warning: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.x.hostname.com does not resolve to address xxx.xxx.xx.x: No address associated with hostname
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem: disabling TLS support
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: warning: TLS library problem: 28718:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem','r'):
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: warning: TLS library problem: 28718:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: warning: TLS library problem: 28718:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:722:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem: disabling TLS support
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: warning: TLS library problem: 28719:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem','r'):
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: warning: TLS library problem: 28719:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: warning: TLS library problem: 28719:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:722:
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: warning: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.x.hostname.com does not resolve to address xxx.xxx.xx.x: No address associated with hostname
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: warning: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.x.hostname.com does not resolve to address xxx.xxx.xx.x: No address associated with hostname
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: connect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]: QUIT\r\n
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28713]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]: QUIT\r\n
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28714]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]: QUIT\r\n
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/smtpd[28718]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]: QUIT\r\n
Jan  9 00:27:19 xxxxxxxx postfix/submission/smtpd[28719]: disconnect from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with `/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem` Check that the file exists and Dovecot has permission to read it, or disable the SSL functionality.

On my Ubuntu machine, dovecot.pem is in /etc/dovecot, with user root and group dovecot.

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot package normally delivers a wrapper script `/usr/share/doc/dovecot-<version>/mkcert.sh`. Try it to generate your self-signed certificate.

Comment: what if I was given my certificate by the CA root? (i.e.: I don't want a self-signed one)